# Elisp destructuring-bind for cons cell?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to do

```
(destructuring-bind (start end) (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
```

But `bounds-of-thing-at-point` returns a cons cell and not a list, so
`destructuring-bind` doesn't work.
What could work for this case?

Comment: `(destructuring-bind (start . end) (cons 'x 'y) (message "%s %s"))` works for me. What version of Emacs is that?

Comment: Works perfectly, @wvxvw. Didn't think of using the dot. But the docstring wasn't very informative. Can you post the answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since `destructuring-bind` is a macro from `cl` package, it may be worthwhile to look into Common Lisp documentation for more examples.

[This page](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_de.htm) shows the syntax of the macro. Note the `(wholevar reqvars optvars . var)`. Though I'm not sure `cl` version of `destructuring-bind` actually supports all of the less common cases (many keywords only make sense when used with Common Lisp macros / functions, but don't have that meaning in Emacs Lisp).

Thus:

```
(destructuring-bind (start . end) (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol) ;...)
```

should work.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use

```
(pcase-let ((`(,start . ,end) (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
  ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think on anything as elegant as destructuring-bind, but this would work:

```
(let* ((b (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
       (start (car b))
       (end   (cdr b)))
  ...)
```

Comment: You've stored the bounds to `b`, then tried to access them from `x`.

Comment: Fixed!  Thanks for pointing it out (anyway, wvxvw answer is better, as it specifically addresses what abo-abo was trying to do)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays we can use [`-let` in dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-let-varlist-rest-body). It is like `pcase-let`, just a bit cleaner:

```lisp
(-let (((start . end) (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
  ...)
```